# same cdb command was producing different results when running it through Perl and Command Prompt

Tags: perl, windbg, symbols

We run CDB through a website on dump files to analyze the dumps. We run the following command

```
c:\PROGRA~1\DEBUGG~1\cdb.exe -z    "C:\Progra~1\BitNam~1\apache2\htdocs\dumps\dumpfile.dmp" -lines -c ".logopen C:\Progra~1\BitNam~1\apache2\htdocs\dumps\temp\ministack_manual.txt; !sym noisy;.reload;!analyze -v;.ecxr;!for_each_frame dv /t;.logclose;
```

When we run the CDB through command prompt, it could load the symbol files for Microsoft component and works file. But, when the same command runs through the website, CDB couldn't find the symbols for Microsoft components.
The code is written in Perl and below is the snippet of code that runs CDB.

```
sub setSymbolPath{
        $ENV{'_NT_SYMBOL_PATH'} = 'SRV*c:\\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;
                                    SRV*c:\\websymbols*http://ctxsym.citrix.com/symbols;                                 
                                    ';
setSymbolPath();        
## $dump_file is the full path to the dump file with a file name
## $mini_stack is the full path to the output file with a file name
open (DUMPFILE, "c:\\PROGRA~1\\DEBUGG~1\\cdb.exe  
                -z \"$dump_file\" -lines -c \".logopen $mini_stack;!sym     noisy;.reload;!analyze -v;.ecxr;!for_each_frame dv /t;.logclose;q\" |");
close DUMPFILE;
```

Comment: "But, when the same command runs through the website", you need to provide more details. What web server? Show a short reproducible CGI script that does not work.

Comment: Is there a newline in the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH? I'd remove it. Try the `-y` command line option instead of setting an environment variable. Environment variables do often not become active immediately (google for the difference between `set` and `setx`).

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured it was a issue with symbols not being available on the located path. they were being purged after a periodic interval and hence caused this issue.